# Trying to pull next appointment from a list of dates

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.1 database with a selection of appointment dates as below from a table (appts):

```
id  |   apptdate  
---|-----------  
1   |  2017-05-01  
2   |  2017-05-07  
3   |  2017-05-14  
4   |  2017-05-21  
5   |  2017-05-28
```

I am trying to pull the next appointment from this list.

If the `current_date` is 2017-05-05, I would like the result to be 2017-05-07.

If the `current_date` is before the last `apptdate`, this works:

```
SELECT apptdate FROM appts WHERE apptdate >= current_date
ORDER BY apptdate
LIMIT 1
```

However, if the `current_date` is after the last `apptdate`, I would like to select the last `apptdate`.

In the example above, if `current_date` is 2017-06-15, I would like the result to be 2017-05-28.

Answer (score 0):

```
select apptdate
from (
    (
        select apptdate
        from appts
        where apptdate >= current_date
        order by apptdate
        limit 1
    )
    union all

    select max(apptdate)
    from appts
) s
order by apptdate
limit 1
```

Comment: Looks like you cannot return a result from a DO function.

Comment: @kipsoft: How does an anonymous `do` block relate to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use OR condition with MAX(apptdate)

> ```
> SELECT apptdate 
> FROM appts 
> WHERE (apptdate >= '2017-05-08' OR apptdate = (select max(apptdate) from appts))
> ORDER BY apptdate
> LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | apptdate   |
> | :--------- |
> | 2017-05-14 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT apptdate 
> FROM appts 
> WHERE (apptdate >= '2017-06-15' OR apptdate = (select max(apptdate) from appts))
> ORDER BY apptdate
> LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | apptdate   |
> | :--------- |
> | 2017-05-28 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80bd18ff496e84ae0fd24871fe6788c8)*

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below query

```
DO
$do$  
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM appts WHERE apptdate >= current_date) THEN
  SELECT apptdate FROM appts WHERE apptdate >= current_date
         ORDER BY apptdate LIMIT 1;
ELSE
  SELECT apptdate FROM appts 
         ORDER BY apptdate DESC LIMIT 1;
END IF;
END
$do$
```

This query uses the `IF ELSE END IF` control structure, with the condition based on the `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Can you point to where "IF ELSE END IF" is a valid SQL statement in the PostgreSQL manuals? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/

Comment: This code throws the following error: 

ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF".

Comment: @kipsoft Updated

Comment: @RichardHuxton  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54514

Comment: Still getting the same error on IF (Postgres 9.1.12)

Comment: @kipsoft was missing `BEGIN`. Added

Comment: Tried BEGIN and got ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 2:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143796/discussion-between-kipsoft-and-dhruvjoshi).